# How to write a WHERE statement based on the value of a CASE statement?

Tags: mysql

The following query returns a result set of all the `new_name` from the table `names`

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN nickname = '' THEN fullname ELSE nickname END AS new_name,       
    FROM names
```

I'm trying to search by `new_name` using the following query

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN nickname = '' THEN fullname ELSE nickname END AS new_name,       
    FROM names
    WHERE new_name LIKE '%Joh%'
```

However I get the error

**Unknown column 'new_name' in 'where clause'**

Is there a way I get this functionality to work without using a subquery?

Comment: You have a typo - the ; after the from clause. It that it?

Comment: @SteveMallory - Good catch but I don't think that's the problem.  I simplified the query for sake of example, and in doing so created a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you repeat the `case` in the `where` clause, the statement will work:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN nickname = '' THEN fullname ELSE nickname END AS new_name      
FROM names
WHERE (CASE WHEN nickname = '' THEN fullname ELSE nickname END) LIKE '%Joh%'
```

It wouldn't be fast, because it wouldn't use indexes, but it should work.

A somewhat better approach would be as follows:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN nickname = '' THEN fullname ELSE nickname END AS new_name      
FROM names
WHERE (nickname like '%Joh%') or (fullname LIKE '%Joh%')
```

This will return the same results, but it can use indexes on `nickname` and `fullname` if you define them, **EDIT** and change the second operand of `LIKE` to not use the leading `%`.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight.  I'm using this in an autocomplete with 0 delay between a keystroke and the execution of the query so the speed upgrade in the second example was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: That won't use indexes either! `LIKE` doesn't use index when the value starts with `%`, and also even if it could, it can only use *one* index and the `OR` precludes using an index

Comment: It's okay, I have another statement `WHERE user_id = ?` so the execution order first goes by that statement, and then checks for the nickname.  But that's a good point you brought up that I didn't know of.

Comment: @Bohemian Oh, you're right, I missed the `%` at the beginning, assuming the more usual "starts with" semantics. I updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN nickname = '' THEN fullname ELSE nickname END AS new_name,       
    FROM names
    WHERE 
       (CASE
        WHEN nickname = '' THEN fullname ELSE nickname END) LIKE '%Joh%';
```

replace the column name with the whole `case ... when ... then ... end`

Answer (score 1):

To me it makes more sense to use coalesce function, assuming nickname is either `NULL` or populated...

```
SELECT COALESCE(nickname,filename)
FROM   table
WHERE COALESCE(nickname,filename) LIKE '%JOE%'
```